# Get every third element from a list

Tags: python, list

For example if I have a list like the following

```
lst = [1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200, 3, 30, 300];
```

How could I get back `[1, 2, 3]`? Basically it would be starting from the  first number, and every third number.

Comment: Is the fact that the element is a single digit the only condition you have?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - all of the information was in the original version. The text speaking about "a single digit" was referring to the possible regex that would match `1,2,3` - but not the condition of "every third element".

Comment: @Lix I just removed the `regex` tag, I am not sure what are you referring to. All the [other changes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20457638/revisions) were made by OP himself.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - I'm talking about your (now deleted) comment. The OP's edit didn't render your answer invalid - it didn't change the underlying question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The step argument using slice notation.

```
>>> lst[::3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

**Update**:

Take a look at this post: [Python's `slice notation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation), it will explain further in detail.

Comment: Do you have a psychic crystal ball debugger that we are not aware of?

Comment: Haha, I wish, I just looked at the list, he said 1, 2, 3 and assumed I suppose.

Comment: Well, you're the only one that got it :P +1

Answer (score 0):

if don;t exactly understand your question , you could use the built in sorted function to sort it and then get the first 3 elements

```
s = sorted(lst)[:3]
```

if you want 1 or 2  or 3 or whatever its there in the list

```
[x for x in lst if x in range(1,4)]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for. The question states that the output should be every third element starting from (and including) the first element. `"starting from the first number, and every third number"`

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200, 3, 30, 300]

print [lst[i] for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 3)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for item in lst:
    if item in [1,2,3]:
        new_lst.append(item)
```

or shorter using list comprehension:

```
new_lst=[item for item in lst if item in [1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple list comprehension:

```
[x for x in lst if x < 10 and x >= 0]
```